# Как получить адрес где я нахожусь?

Tags: java, android

Как реализовать что бы при нажатии кнопки получить свое место положения. Не координаты а адрес улицы.

**Может есть статьи или примеры на эту тему?**

Наверное надо Яндекс.Карты использовать.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

для этого есть разные услуги. и Яндекс и Google.

используйте geocoder

```
Geocoder geocoder;
List<Address> addresses;
geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1); // Где 1 это максимальное количество резултат для этой координат, по документу советуется использовать 1 до 5

String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0); // Если есть еще другие адреса, используйте это
String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
String state = addresses.get(0).getAdminArea();
String country = addresses.get(0).getCountryName();
String postalCode = addresses.get(0).getPostalCode();
String knownName = addresses.get(0).getFeatureName(); // Если есть даст результат, если нет NULL
```

---

попробуйте использовать различный сайтов как

1. http://www.latlong.net/Show-Latitude-Longitude.html

коди в анроиде

1. http://www.androidauthority.com/get-location-address-android-app-628764/
2. http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/training/location/display-address.html

Comment: Спасибо буду пробовать